# Special Progress Bar using jquery & css

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I want to create a progress bar that is devided into sections like in the following link: [Progress Bar Example](https://www.zocdoc.com/booking/start?startTime=634838256000000000&professionalId=41297&locationId=29436&specialtyId=345&procedureId=1296&referrerType=&repeatPatient=false)

I have two access tables: Projects, Stages. I need to show the stage per for project in a progress bar described above.

Can anybody help me creating/ using an existing such a progress bar that is built and refers to those tables.

Same question was aleardy asked here but the provided answers were incomprehensible to me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The link you showed just reloaded the page.  It would have been a little more complicated without reloading the page, but all you have to do is use a rule like:

(in first page)

```
Projects { background-image: url('complete.gif'); }
Stages{ background-image: url('incomplete.gif'); }
```

(in second page)

```
Projects { background-image: url('complete.gif'); }
Stages{ background-image: url('complete.gif'); }
```

Comment: I am new to jquery & css. Can you be more specific please?